# Query for documents with given set of attributes in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm writing a query in the mongo.exe as follows:

```
db.sheep.find( { "timestamp" : {
     "$gt":ISODate("2015-05-15T10:00:00.000z"),
     "$lt":ISODate("2015-05-15T10:05:10.000z") } },
     {"x":1,"y":1,"z":1,"timestamp":1})
```

However, some of the returned documents have `timestamp` but no `x`, `y`, `z`. How do I return only documents that have both `timestamp` and `x y z`?

I presume there is some pretty straightforward logic to add to the query but I can't seem to find anything when searching around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter, the filter object, determines the criteria a match must fulfill. In this case, the timestamp must be in a certain interval.

The second parameter is a projection, primarily used to remove fields that are unnecessary, especially if the data is large (like some embedded binary document, a file or something).

If you want to make sure that the documents have `x`, `y` and `z` set, you can check that using [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/):

```
db.sheep.find( 
{ 
  "timestamp" : {
   "$gt" : ISODate("2015-05-15T10:00:00.000z"),
   "$lt" : ISODate("2015-05-15T10:05:10.000z")
  },
  "x": { "$exists": true }, 
  "y": { "$exists": true },
  "z": { "$exists": true } 
});
```

However, be warned that this is usually a sign of *bad schema design*. `$exists`, by definition, has worst-case selectivity, so **don't expect these queries to be fast**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$exists` operator.

```
db.sheep.find( 
{ 
    "timestamp" : {
       "$gt":ISODate("2015-05-15T10:00:00.000z"),
       "$lt":ISODate("2015-05-15T10:05:10.000z")
    },
    "x": { "exists": true }, 
    "y": { "exists": true },
    "z": { "exists": true } 
},
{"x":1,"y":1,"z":1,"timestamp":1})
```